Как получить список ссылок из Меню сообщества вКонтакте?

В API вКонтакте метод groups.getById не возвращает данные о Меню сообщества.
Есть ли другой легальный способ?
Или нужно парсить страницу сообщества?

Невозможно с помощью API (по состоянию на 2024 год).
Ответ службы поддержки:
Методов для работы с меню сообщества — не существует. Если ситуация изменится в будущем, мы отразим это на портале для разработчиков, но подсказать по срокам, даже примерным, увы, не можем.
